Qemu kvm Failed to autostart VM Cannot get interface MTU on 'br100': No such device
I am using OL9.2 and libvirt version: 10.0.0
I am trying to add an vm to autostart with sudo virsh autostart <vm_name>.
On host reboot vm did not start and virtqemud shows this log:
virtqemud[1131]: Cannot get interface MTU on 'br100': No such device 
virtqemud[1131]: internal error: Failed to autostart VM 'name': Cannot get interface MTU on 'br100': No such device
br100 is a bridge that I created manually on host machine and its up and running (one of vm interfaces its bridged to it)
What I have tried is adding br100 to /etc/qemu-kvm/bridge.conf but it did not help.

update:
I fixed it by adding delay to virtqemud

sudo systemctl edit virtqemud.service

[Unit]
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target


